# My sound card is not recognized by Kali

Tags: kali-linux, audio, settings

I am using Kali 3.0 in a VMware virtual machine. My computer is running on Windows 7. I have no sound since I installed Kali, I tried a lot of commands that involves `alsa` and `pulseaudio`, delete and reinstall but nothing worked.

My most recent attempt is using `lspci` to find my hardware,
and it seems that Kali doesn't recognize my sound card:

```
root@kali:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX AGP bridge (rev 01)
00:07.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 08)
00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:07.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:07.7 System peripheral: VMware Virtual Machine Communication Interface (rev 10)
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
00:10.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev 01)
00:11.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI bridge (rev 02)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB controller: VMware USB1.1 UHCI Controller
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
02:02.0 USB controller: VMware USB2 EHCI Controller
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried non-kali distros? Did you read the arch wiki>

Comment: Have you provided a virtualised sound card to your VM?

Comment: As @Braiam suggests, try a different OS, maybe Debian or Ubuntu (which sometimes does better at the hardware detection). And I'd try that both as a regular install, and as a Vmware guest. Is the card working on Win 7? But roaima's comment might be the most useful of all.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question. It's not a dupe in any way of that Kali question, which has nothing to do with sound cards. I mean, seriously?

Comment: @FaheemMitha if the OP demonstrated a level of competence that _should_ be associated with Kali I suspect this possible duplicate wouldn't have been suggested.

Comment: @roaima I also have flagged it as such initially. The question might has its merits *without* the kali tag for possibly being recurrent the lack of distinction  between using the real hw or the virtualized one.

Comment: @roaima I have no idea why there is *any* specific level of competence associated with Kali. What's so special about it?

Comment: @FaheemMitha https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/what-should-we-do-about-kali-linux-questions and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: @roaima Yes, I've seen those already. I don't see how that is relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kali won't ever see your real sound card as this is a VM. (Unless you provide it directly via passthrough, which is more of an advanced topic.)

You have to configure the VMWare provider to give a virtualised sound card to that particular VM if your card is supported by VMWare. As per the `lspci` output it is evident that step was not done, as as such the VM thinks it has no sound card.

Once you have a virtualised card, you will have to install the drivers for the virtualised card, and not for the real one.